# Netherlands Tram / Train ticketing

Tags: netherlands

The Dutch GVB transportation features and all daypass for the [Amsterdam Tram](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Renaissance+Amsterdam+Hotel,+Kattengat,+Amsterdam,+Netherlands/Rijksmuseum,+Museumstraat+1,+1071+XX+Amsterdam,+Netherlands/@52.369293,4.8731205,14z/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x47c609c875b11085:0x46ac8e5b5d89c087!2m2!1d4.894641!2d52.377955!1m5!1m1!1s0x47c609eec1bb16e5:0xd54373ae6a408585!2m2!1d4.8852188!2d52.3599976!3e3).    I am strongly considering using it for transportation between the Rennaisance Hotel (near Centraal station) and the Rijksmuseum.

Is there an all-day transportation pass the includes both the trips from:

- Schiphol to Centraal station and
- [Centraal to Rijksmuseum](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Renaissance+Amsterdam+Hotel,+Kattengat,+Amsterdam,+Netherlands/Rijksmuseum,+Museumstraat+1,+1071+XX+Amsterdam,+Netherlands/@52.369293,4.8731205,14z/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x47c609c875b11085:0x46ac8e5b5d89c087!2m2!1d4.894641!2d52.377955!1m5!1m1!1s0x47c609eec1bb16e5:0xd54373ae6a408585!2m2!1d4.8852188!2d52.3599976!3e3)?

Does said GVB day-pass include transportation between Airport and Central or is there a possible GVB daypass 'upgrade'?

Update: I need transportation from:

1. Schiphol to Central Station, check into hotel and then
2. Centraal to Rijksmusem (day visit)
3. Rijks to Centraal  (return to hotel)

Comment: If you want to do one train trip and one tram trip, or even two tram trips, a day pass is likely going to be more expensive.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

- The €17 “[Amsterdam Travel Ticket](https://www.discoverholland.com/amsterdam-travel-ticket)” covers transportation to and from Schiphol by train or using bus 397 (operated by Connexxion) and all public transportation in Amsterdam (in particular the bus, trams and metros operated by GVB). [This offering from Connexxion](https://www.connexxion.nl/amsterdam-and-region-travel-ticket/1244/amsterdam-and-region-travel-ticket/4065) seems similar, not sure why there is a price difference.
- [GVB offers a much cheaper day ticket](https://en.gvb.nl/gvb-dag-meerdagenkaart) but it would not cover NS trains or the Connexxion bus to Schiphol. It is still possible to reach Amsterdam city center from the airport using bus 69 (as this one is operated by GVB) but the connections are likely to be longer and more cumbersome.

Note that individual tickets or a train ticket + a GVB day pass for the two trips inside the city are likely to be cheaper but I am assuming you also appreciate a day pass for the convenience.